# Why is my Date create not working in php?

Tags: php

I have a messaging system and I am converting dates. I am converting a date and so I take the users timezone (New york as an example) then I use the date() function. But when I remove the date_create() it works and outputs : 2020-09-06 08:45:25. But nothing get outputted when there is the date create. Here is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
        $date1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $date2 = date_create($date1);
        echo $date2;
```

Comment: There is no output in your code...

Comment: When I add echo $date2 nothing is outputted

Comment: Did you  just want format `$date1` to this `Y-m-d H:i:s` ?

Comment: Use `echo $date1;`

Comment: there is an exception or severe error. turn up the error_reporting & activate display_errors

Comment: enable error reporting you should be getting: *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in ...* you're echoing an object :/ I think you're after this: https://3v4l.org/8otbk

Comment: How do I fix this? Basically, I want to convert it into a datetime to use the date_diff and the date_sub but then be able to echo it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact [date_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) return Object of class DateTime so you can't echo it, to do that you should convert it into string by using [date_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) like :

```
echo date_format($date2, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```